# jquery remove duplicate elements after loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a plugin which shows me Images in a 360 3D-View.
If i open the Webpage, in the Background are loading 36 Pictures and after loading the Pictures the Plugin take one Picture and show it.

So, my Problem is that i can do some other actions on the page before all pictures are loaded and i load some other data after i click on a button with ajax and if i do other actions BEFORE all Pictures are loaded, i get duplicate entries in the HTML Code and some pictures are shown and other not something like this (this code generate the 3D Plugin).

```
<div>
<div rel="0" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
    <img src="img0.png" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="1">
    <img src="img1.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="2" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
    <img src="img3.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="3" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
    <img src="img3.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
    <img src="img1.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="3" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
    <img src="img3.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="3" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
    <img src="img3.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
<div rel="0" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
    <img src="img0.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;" class="3dweb">
</div>
```

my solution was that after all images are loaded, i delete the duplicate entries and show only one picture.

the problem is that my javascript/jquery code freeze the browser and i don't know why, perhaps i think it gives a better solution but i havent a better solution.

my javascript/jquery code

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 4000);

function myTimer() {
  if($('[rel=35]').length > 0) {
    $('.js-loading-car-image').css("display","none");
    var x = 1;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 35) {
        var tmp = $('[rel='+i+']').next();

        if($(tmp).attr("rel") == x) {
            x++;
            i++;
        } else {
            $('[rel='+i+']').next().remove();
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<36;i++) {
        var display = $('[rel='+i+']').css("display");
        if(display=="block") {
            $('[rel='+i+']').css("display", "none");
        }
    }
    $('[rel=26]').css("display","block");


    $('.js-3d-images').fadeIn("slow");
    myStopFunction();
  }
}

function myStopFunction() {
   clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Anybody ideas why the Browers are freezing or which i could/should do better?

Comment: Hi, according to my understanding, what you want to do is remove duplicate elements after all the data had loaded. Is that the solution are you looking for ?

Comment: yes that is the solution im looking for.
all "rel" have to be in the right order. 
first the element with "rel=0", then "rel=1" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some values from your code and create a basic structure. Check whether this is the solution you are looking for

```js
var dataset = $('#image-data > div');
var rel = [];
for(var j = 0 ; j < dataset.length; j++ ){
  var x = $(dataset[j]).attr('rel');
  if( jQuery.inArray(x, rel) >= 0){
     $(dataset[j]).remove();
  }
  rel.push(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-data">
<div rel="0">
    <img src="img0.png" alt="rel 0">
</div>
<div rel="1">
    <img src="img1.png" alt="rel 1">
</div>
<div rel="2">
    <img src="img2.png" alt="rel 2">
</div>
<div rel="3">
    <img src="img3.png" alt="rel 3">
</div>
<div rel="1">
    <img src="img1.png" alt="rel 1">
</div>
<div rel="3">
    <img src="img3.png" alt="rel 3">
</div>
<div rel="3">
    <img src="img3.png" alt="rel 3">
</div>
<div rel="0">
    <img src="img0.png" alt="rel 0">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works great, thx.
now i found another problem with the plugin, because this solution not solved the problem, but it shouldnt your problem.

Comment: Happy to hear that my solution worked for you somehow. Cheers @Mark